# Kotlin idiomatic if-let logic

Tags: kotlin

Does Kotlin have a more idiomatic way of doing this?

```
val someVal = ...

val newVal = someVal.let{
   if(<some_condition>){
      <return some value>
   }else{
      it
   }
}
```

So it's basically, if some condition is true, do something and return its value.  Otherwise, just return the original value.  I think of it kind of like `takeIf`, but there's a value to return instead of `null`  (Actually, `takeIf` is backwards, if the condition is **not** met then it returns `null`, but you get the idea.)

Comment: What is the point of `.let` in your code?

Comment: Question would have been better if you used concrete examples that could be executed.

Comment: I think the question is not answerable until we know if `someVal` can be `null`, and if so, what `newVal` should be set to in that case.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is to use `takeIf()`, as you suggest — though you have to flip the condition — in combination with the elvis operator:

```
val newVal = someVal.takeIf{ !<some_condition> } ?: <some value>
```

Alternatively, if the condition makes more sense without being flipped, then you can use `takeUnless()`:

```
val newVal = someVal.takeUnless{ <some_condition> } ?: <some value>
```

Obviously these will only work safely if `someVal` is not nullable (or your condition treats `null` appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

No, the way that you expressed it is the most idiomatic way, although you the use of `let` is unnecessary, unless you meant to handle nulls, but you didn't mention that in your question. If nulls are possible, you need to specify what should happen in the null case - do we return null, a value, or throw an exception?

```
val now = LocalTime.now()
val earliestPM =　if (now.isBefore(LocalTime.NOON)) LocalTime.NOON else now
```